# Check boxes in Angular not accepting latest values on Submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I defined a static `array` as below in my TypeScript:

```
  rights: any[] = [
    { right: "Add", value: true },
    { right: "Update", value: false },
    { right: "Delete", value: false },
    { right: "Edit", value: true }
  ]
```

In my HTML I am looping in & showing in the checkboxes which are `true` gets checked by default. Now the problem here is when I change the value it still returns the same values as defined in the TypeScript, and I want new updated values.

```
<h4 *ngFor="let r of rights">
 <input type="checkbox" [checked]="r.value">{{r.right}}
</h4>
<button (click)="go(rights)">Update</button>
```

& then in TypeScript, I am logging it to console.

```
 go(rights){
    console.log(rights);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to way binding via `ngModel`.

```
<h4 *ngFor="let r of rights">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="r.value">{{r.right}}
</h4>
<button (click)="go(rights)">Update</button>
```

You need also to import `FormsModule` in your module to make `[(ngModel)]` work.

Comment: Correct Solved in just few seconds. Thanks a lot brother

Comment: Yes imported got the solution. I will accept & upvote tomorrow buddy as I have reached today to a maximum limit. Sorry tomorrow definatley I will upvote & accept the answer. Thank You So Much. :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working just because you've chosen a wrong type of data binding.

Data binding is a mechanism for coordinating what users see and can do with the given data. You define bindings between binding sources and HTML elements which let the framework do the work.

Angular provides several types of data binding, which for your case, you needed to have a `Two-way` data binding, which merely means your changes on the target element changes the source, and any change on the source data changes the target element visible value.

Two-way data binding works as `Interpolation` and `Event`

In your case, you just need to change the checkboxes to:

`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="r.value"> {{r.right}}`